# Display name instead editor field in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have in my edit form displayed: Username, TimeZone, Customer...

I don't whant to be able to edit username, just display his name.

This code I use in View:

```
    <label>Username </label> 
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.username)
    </div>
```

So what to put instead EditorFor, that will display username (just for reading, not for editing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use `@Html.DisplayFor` instead? This will just display the username as a label. Or, if you wish to use `@Html.EditorFor` or `@Html.EditorForModel`, you can create a custom [editor template](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nunos/archive/2010/02/08/quick-tips-about-asp-net-mvc-editor-templates.aspx) for your `username` property, and in the editor template, just display the content instead of enabling editing.

Also, I would recomment you exclude this property during model binding by using `[Bind(Exclude="username")]` with your model parameter in your `POST` action method, to protect from injection attacks. More about this [here](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/03/12/complete-guide-to-mass-assignment-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

find solution:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.username, new {disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })
```